# Are objects like String and Number, etc...considered "constructor functions"?

Tags: javascript

I've been reading tutorials for a few weeks now and I've just figured out that when I use the prototype property on a constructor function, the key/value pairs on that prototype property are copied to the **proto** property of the newly instantiated object.

```
function F(){};
F.prototype.k = "v";
console.dir(F.k)//logs "undefined"
console.dir(F.prototype.k)//logs "v"

var o = new F;
console.dir(o.k)//logs "v"
```

So, key "k" is on the prototype property in the constructor and then transfers this to the **proto** property of newly instantiated object "o" which is why it can be accessed as if it were just a normal key/value pair on the object.  Ok, that makes sense to me...but I thought about it and I've seen people use the new keyword for built-in things like String (although this is usually not done)

```
var s = new String;
```

the above code is an example of the way a new string item could be created the same way objects can be instantiated based on constructor functions.  This made me wonder "is String just a constructor function????!"  So I tested this out:

```
console.dir(String.prototype)
```

And I got a whole list of exactly the same properties that are attached to s.  So, is "String" just a constructor function?  The same behavior seems to be true of these items:

```
console.dir(String.prototype);
console.dir(Number.prototype);
console.dir(Boolean.prototype);
console.dir(Array.prototype);
console.dir(Object.prototype);
console.dir(Function.prototype);
console.dir(Date.prototype);
```

They all appear to behave exactly the same as constructor functions.  They are even all capitalized rather than camelcase.  Are they just constructor functions with a few built-in bells and whistles added to them?

Comment: Yes, they are constructors, but some primitive literals don't exatly correspond to an instance of the type constructor, in the case of strings, or numbers for example, that's why you shouldn't use `new String`, or `new Number`.

Comment: The primitives have their own constructors but it's considered bad practice to modify them.

Comment: Yeah I noticed that also...If I instantiate an object from something like String: var s = new String; console.dir(typeof s); it returns "object" not string.  And yet if I type console.dir(typeof "hello"); it returns string.  I don't understand why this happens but I'm guessing something flashy behind the scenes is going on.  "typeof" doesn't produce the constructor function type, it seems to be reflecting something else.

Comment: It's not clear what has surprised you: the fact that `prototype` is "copied" into instance?

Comment: if you use "new " before a constructor call, you always get back an object. using number and string literals produces primatives that are auto-cast to objects if needed, like when someone says "bob".blink()

Comment: What surprised me was that these were constructor functions and I never thought of them like that.

Comment: @Allan Socks: **any** function might be called with `new` keyword. So technically any function is "a constructor"

Comment: @zerkms: no, only if the function returns "this" (or nothing) is it a constructor (among other requirements). that's why (new btoa("bob")) or (new :"".blink) is not a constructor, even if we try to pretend it is.

Comment: @dandavis: that's curious - "only if the function returns "this" (or nothing) is it a constructor" --- where does this requirement come from?

Comment: function Person(name){return {name:name}} is NOT a constructor, namely because there can be no inheritance changed to Person.prototype unless you return this or let this be the implicit new-caused return.

Comment: @dandavis: well, who does define those requirements for the function to be treated as a constructor? Is it somewhere in ECMAScript?

Comment: @zerkms: how about when instance.constructor points to the same function that spawned the instance ?(without modification).

Comment: @dandavis: uhm, is it an official requirement? My point is still here - any function is a constructor. Why? Because I don't see anything in ECMAScript that would prevent me calling it so. I'm flexible to accept that I'm wrong if there is an explicit definition in the standard that makes me wrong.

Comment: http://es5.github.io/#x4.3.4 says: *"constructor: Function object that creates and initialises objects."* and then also mentions the `prototype` property. How you want to interpret that I'll leave to you guys ;) But from my understanding, a function called with `new` acts as a constructor in this moment (what happens to `this` is another matter, it doesn't say a constructor has to *return* that particular object).

Comment: invoking any old function with "new " does not make a "Constructor" as most understand it to be: providing inheritance, correct implicit property linking, re-apply()-ability etc.

Comment: @dandavis: "as most understand it to be" --- that's when instead of subjective points the standard comes into play. We either use the official terminology, or not use anything at all - because otherwise we won't be able to communicate efficiently.

Comment: @zerkms: i know from experience that no standard is ever explicit enough to satisfy everyone. besides, de facto is more usable than de jure for humans to discuss such topics.

Answer (score 3):

There are 6 data types in JavaScript:

- Boolean
- Number
- String
- Null
- Undefined
- Object

The first five are so called *primitive types*. Three of the primitive types, Boolean, Number and String, also have an equivalent Object implementation.

Whenever you use *(Boolean|Number|String) literals*, you are creating a value of that corresponding type.

You can also create Boolean, Number and String *objects* by calling the corresponding constructor function with the `new` operator:

```
var s = 'foo'; // type string
var s2 = new String('foo'); // type object
```

Now, the reason why you can access properties on both of them is that JavaScript **auto-boxes** primitive values. I.e. when you are trying to access a property on a primitive value, it will temporarily convert the value to an object and access the property.

So

```
var v = "foo";
alert(v.length);
```

is essentially

```
var v = "foo";
alert((new String(v)).length);
```

---

If the `String`, `Number` or `Boolean` function is called *without* the `new` keyword, they will return a primitive value instead, which makes them act as conversion functions.

---

And to round this up: **Every** function has a `prototype` property, every function can potentially act as a constructor. Whether it really does depends on the implementation of the function.